# Java backend RESTful server application with CDI

Tags: java, oracle, rest, cdi, backend

My task is to create a JavaEE application with `RESTful` services using `CDI`. I would have to get the data from an `Oracle` database.

I have researched on the internet on how to make this, but I just couldn't find a project/guide which was using all that I needed. I have created an entity class, but I can't figure out how to deal with the data from the database, just `crud` for the database.

My entity class:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String author;
    private String title;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "author", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author= author;
    }

    @Column(name = "title", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title= title;
    }

}
```

Any help, or link to guides is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are plenty of examples, e.g. http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-example

Comment: Why are the answers being downvoted?

Comment: Dont ask me. Thanks for your links by the way :)

Comment: No problem, were they any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a tutorial that combines JPA with jdbc. Let the jpa handle all the talking to the database, you can focus on developing. I suggest using spring.

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-oracle-example/) is an example that uses Spring.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) is an example using Eclipse-link.

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/) is how you connect to an oracle database.

[This](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/) is a great tutorial that cobers the whole shebang from scratch to adding and reading from your db.

Answer (score -1):

I know little about `CDI`, but `contoller`, `dao` and `service` are different levels. You can find tutorials about `restful service with CDI` and `crud with oracle`. `Spring date redis` will be an alternative if you don't have to use CDI.

`Hibernate` and `spring data jpa` will be a good option for crud with oracle.